# Conditional statement printing values twice python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I am testing my script in which i am passing two values to compare. It goes through two conditional statements. I have carried out some debugging and it prints out the same expression twice which is "Current value is in range". It first prints it out from the first loop and then from the second loop. I am not sure why my code is doing that. It should only print that out once and get out of the else statement and not go in to the second else statement which it is currently doing. What is that I am doing wrong to stop this.

```
def compare_sizes(previous_size, current_size):

    subtract_f1_f2 = int(current_size - previous_size)
    range_num = 0.4
    range_previous_day = int(previous_size * range_num)


  if subtract_f1_f2 > 0 and range_previous_day > 0 and subtract_f1_f2 >= range_previous_day:

    whole_percent = subtract_f1_f2 / previous_size * 100
    print (human_bytes(previous_size) +" -> " + human_bytes(current_size) + " " +
                            "+" + str(whole_percent) + " % bigger" + "\n")
    return
  else:
    print("Current Value Is In Range")
  if  subtract_f1_f2 <0 and subtract_f1_f2 <= range_previous_day:
    whole_percent = abs(subtract_f1_f2 / previous_size * 100)
    print (human_bytes(previous_size) + " -> " + human_bytes(current_size) + " " + str(
            whole_percent) + " % smaller" + "\n")
  else:
    print("Current Value Is In Range")



result = compare_sizes(1000,1400)# 40% Bigger
result = compare_sizes(1000,1399)#  In Range
# result = compare_sizes(1000,599)
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to do that? Why can't both conditions be false? (For example, if subtract_f1_f2 is 1 but range_previous_day is 0).

Comment: This is working as intended. Your conditional's logic is just a little flawed. @DanielRoseman is correct. Also did you mean to indent the second if statement? Because despite the indent it is not nested into the first one. Also I don't see any loops in this code.

Comment: It happens because you logic goes through both else statements. It doesn't match first if, goes to else band print "In range" then it compare second if and doesn't match if as well and automatically goes to second else. I think in your case you can use elif statement with some more condition then just else.

Comment: yes that does make sense. Thanks @SergeyPugach